# How to get JSON / JSONP data using XAMPP local server?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, xampp

I have set up a local server using `XAMPP`. Now I want to get `JSON` / `JSONP` data from that server.

**Side question:**

`Do I need to somehow upload the JSON file on the server? 
Or is there some`PHP`coding for that? IF yes, which?`

I have heard about some `jQuery ajax` call function, but it didnt work for me. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have several way of doing that. if the result is not dynamic you just create a json file on server and get it using URL.

if you want to do it dynamic in response to web page sent to server you can use the built in PHP function json_encode.

Please follow php documenation for [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will check it up!  
My problems is a bit wider than mentioned above. I'd like to ask: When I saved the txt .json .. can I call a specific object in that file?
and then store it in a HTML variable?

The bigger picture behind this are Google Charts.. I need variable from JSON, to be used as Y values on the charts.

Comment: get the json using jquery ajax. in the reponse you'll have access to the object and its properties. this way you can access any propery you want. see documentation for jquery ajax (you'll also have lots of examples here)

Comment: @G Z: I am sorry for bothering you, but I do not have a lot of knowledge of this. On sites, I cannot find step-by-step example on how to do this. I found only explanations of what functions do, that's helpfull, but I cannot solely create an entire code just based on that. So an example fiddle would really be helpfull, if you have maybe some spare time? Does using XAMPP require some special caution while doing this?

Comment: @G Z: I write my own fiddle to try out: http://jsfiddle.net/86aBp/3/ ... can you please correct me? Because it is not working. I have both files in HTDOCS (in XAMPP folder).

Answer (score 0):

i don t think you need to do a lot of things.
json is a way to format data. you can do that returnin an output using json_encode()

exemples and info at http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use `json_encode()` function available in PHP to send the data is JSON format to the client and handle the response in AJAX by mentioning `dataType: json`